# Read from csv file and separate into variable

Tags: c, file, input

I'm trying to separate my input values into 2 different categories. The first array call teamname would hold the the team names and the second array would hold the score for that week. My input file is .csv with the code the way it is everything is stored in the as a string instead of 2 separate variables. Also I'm not to program savvy and am only familiar with the  library.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILEIN "data.csv"
#define FILEOUT "matrix.csv"

int main (void)
{
    double nfl[32][32], teamscore[32];
    char teamname[30];
    int n;
    FILE *filein_ptr;
    FILE *fileout_ptr;

    filein_ptr = fopen (FILEIN, "r");
    fileout_ptr = fopen (FILEOUT, "w");

    for (n = 1; n <= 32; n++) {
        fscanf (filein_ptr, "%s  %lf\n", &teamname, &teamscore[n]);
        fprintf (fileout_ptr, "%s    %f\n", teamname, teamscore);
    }

    fclose (filein_ptr);
    fclose (fileout_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I should say that the input file has the first column with team names and the second column with team scores. Any help would be great. Thanks!
Here is a sample input file

- Steelers,20
- Patriots,25
- Raiders,15
- Chiefs,35

Comment: Could you add a sample input file to your question?

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.   Always enable all warnings when compiling, Then fix those warnings.  1) variable `nfi` not used  2) line 20, format `%f` expects `double`, but arg 4 has type `double*`  3) line 19, format `%s` expect `char *` but arg 3 has type `char (*)[40]`  Please fix these problems and post an edit to your question.

Comment: when calling the `fopen()` function, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   when calling the `fscanf()` function, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. (in this case, compare the returned value to 2)   A comma ',' is not 'white space', so must be included in the format string in the call to `fscanf()`   Note: performing error checking would have told you exactly where the problem in your code is located.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to read/understand and adds difficulty when debugging/maintaining.   the 'magic' numbers are:  32 and 30.  Suggest using #define statements or an enum to give those numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: in C, when using the name of an array (for instance 'teamname') it degrades to a pointer to the first byte of the array.   fscanf() expects pointers, so rather than '&teamname' use 'teamname' (no 'address of' operator)

Comment: in the posted code, why keep all the score values, when only one is needed?  suggest changing `teamscore[32]`  to `teamscore`.   When calling `fprintf()`, the parameter: `teamscore`, because it is an array, will output an address rather than the current teams' score.  suggest (if keeping the teamscore variable as an array) using: `teamscore[n]`

Comment: regarding this line: `for (n = 1; n <= 32; n++) {`,  in C, an array of 'x' length, is indexed from 0 to (x-1).   So the line is skipping the first entry in the array and the '<=32' will access one past the end of the array.  this results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.   Suggest using: `for (n = 0; n < 32; n++) {`

Comment: the format specifier for the teamname input field `%s` will include the whole input line including the score.   you probably want the teamname to not include anything starting with the comma ','.  Suggest the `scanf()` format string to be: " %[^,] , %;f".  Notice the spaces and the standalone comma.  The spaces to consume 'white space' and the stand alone comma so it will be consumed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing `&teamname` to `teamname`, there are a few other considerations you may want to look at. The first being, always initialize your variables. While not required, this has a number of positive benefits. For numerical arrays, it initializes all elements preventing an accidental read from an uninitialized value. For character arrays, initializing to `0` insures that the first copy to the string (less than the total length) will be `null-terminated` and also prevents an attempted read from an uninitialized value. It's just good habit:

```
    double teamscore[MAXS] = {0.0};
    char teamname[30] = {0};
    int n = 0;
```

You have defined default values for your `filein_ptr` and `fileout_ptr`, you can do the same for your array sizes. That makes your code easier to maintain by providing a single value to update if your array size needs change.

Next, and this is rather a nit, but an important nit. `main` accept arguments, defined by standard as `int argc, char **argv` (you may also see an `char **envp` on Unix systems, you may seem them both written in equivalent form `char *argv[]` and `char *envp[]`). The point here is to use them to take arguments for your program so you are not stuck with just your hardcoded `data.csv` and `matrix.csv` filenames. You can use your hardcoded values and still provided the user the ability to enter filenames of his choice by using a simple `ternary` operator (e.g. `test ? if true code : if false code;`):

```
    FILE *filein_ptr = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : fopen (FILEIN, "r");
    FILE *fileout_ptr = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "w") : fopen (FILEOUT, "w");
```

There, the *test* `argc > 1` (meaning there is at least one argument given by the user), *if true code* `open (argv[1], "r")` (open the filename given as the argument for reading, and *if false code* `fopen (FILEIN, "r")` open your default if not filename given. The same holds true for your output file. (you must provide them in the correct order).

Then if you *open* a file, you must validate that the file is actually open before you attempt to read from it. While you can test the input and output separately to tell which one failed, you can also use a simple `||` condition to check if either open failed:

```
    if (!filein_ptr || ! fileout_ptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: filein of fileout open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Lastly, if you know the number of lines of data you need to read, an indexed `for` loop as you have is fine, but you will rarely know the number of lines in a data file before hand. Even if using a `for` loop, you still need to check the return of `fscanf` to verify that you actually had 2 valid conversion (and therefore got 2 values you were expecting). Checking the return also provides another benefit. It allows you to continue reading until you no longer get 2 valid conversions from `fscanf`. This provides an easy way to read an unknown number of values from a file. However, you do need to insure you do not try and read more values into your array than they will hold. e.g.:

```
    while (fscanf (filein_ptr, " %29[^,],%lf", teamname, &teamscore[n]) == 2) {
        fprintf (fileout_ptr, "%s    %f\n", teamname, teamscore[n++]);
        if (n == MAXS) {  /* check data doesn't exceed MAXS */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: data exceeds MAXS.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
```

**note:** when using a format specifier that contains a character case (like `"%[^,], ..."`), be aware it will read and include leading and trailing whitespace in the conversion to string. So if your file has `'  Steelers ,..'`, `teamname` will include the whitespace. You can fix the leading whitespace by including a space before the start of the conversion (like `" %29[^,], ..."`) and also limit the number of characters that can be read by specifying a maximum field width. (a trailing whitespace in the case would be easier trimmed after the read)

Putting all the pieces together, you could make your code more flexible and reliable by taking arguments from the user, and validating your file and read operations:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILEIN "data.csv"
#define FILEOUT "matrix.csv"
#define MAXS 32

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* double nfl[MAXS][MAXS] = {{0}}; */
    double teamscore[MAXS] = {0.0};
    char teamname[30] = {0};
    int n = 0;
    FILE *filein_ptr = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : fopen (FILEIN, "r");
    FILE *fileout_ptr = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "w") : fopen (FILEOUT, "w");

    if (!filein_ptr || ! fileout_ptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: filein of fileout open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf (filein_ptr, " %29[^,],%lf", teamname, &teamscore[n]) == 2) {
        fprintf (fileout_ptr, "%s    %f\n", teamname, teamscore[n++]);
        if (n == MAXS) {  /* check data doesn't exceed MAXS */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: data exceeds MAXS.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose (filein_ptr);
    fclose (fileout_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Test Input**

```
$ cat ../dat/teams.txt
Steelers,   20
Patriots,25
    Raiders,    15
    Chiefs,35
```

*note:* the variations in leading whitespace and whitespace between values was intentional.

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/teams ../dat/teams.txt teamsout.txt

$ cat teamsout.txt
Steelers    20.000000
Patriots    25.000000
Raiders    15.000000
Chiefs    35.000000
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Excellent catches on both. Updated.

Comment: Minor `if (n == MAXS)` is in the wrong place as error message prints when there are exactly `MAXS` teams.

Comment: You sure about that one? The little `n++` right before it would insure only `MAXS - 1` elements were filled -- wouldn't it?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I don't know what to say, that answer was very thorough and told me everything I needed to know. I struggled with the code for quite some time before I came to stackoverflow, and I'm so glad I did. Thank you,again.

Comment: Glad I could help. C is one of those languages where just about everybody needs a little help up so they can see above the fray the first time. C is a exact language, fairly simple when you boil the pieces down, there are just a hell of a lot of pieces that need to be boiled down. One piece at a time -- Good luck with your coding.

Comment: the call to to `fread()` in the while loop needs to be preceeded by `n<MAXS &&` so will not read data past the end of the input array `teamscore[]`

Comment: regarding this line: `double teamscore[MAXS] = {0};`, the initializer should be: `{0.0}`  so no conversion is needed

Comment: I updated the initializer, but there is no way the read loop can read beyond the end of the array due to the increment `n++` in `printf` and the immediate check of `n == MAXS` that follows. It may look a little different than you are used to seeing it, but whether you check following index increment at the end of the loop, or in the loop condition itself provides the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to store the team names in an array you should declare a two dimensional array:

```
char team_names[N_OF_TEAMS][MAX_CHAR_IN_NAME];
```

Then, you declare the array for the score. You are using doubles to store the score, aren't them only integers?

```
double scores[N_OF_TEAMS];
```

To read those values you can use:

```
int read_name_and_score( char * fname, int m, char nn[][MAX_CHAR_IN_NAME], double * ss)
{
    FILE *pf;
    int count = 0;

    if (!fname) {
        prinf("Error, no file name.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pf = fopen(fname,'r');
    if (!pf) {
        printf("An error occurred while opening file %s.\n",fname);
        return -2;
    }

    while ( count < m && fscanf(pf, "%[^,],%d\n", nn[count], &ss[count]) == 2 ) count++;

    if (!fclose(pf)) {
        printf("An error occurred while closing file %s.\n",fname);
    };
    return count;
}
```

You need the [^,] to stop scanf from reading the string when finds a , 
The main will be something like:

```
#define N_OF_TEAMS 32
#define MAX_CHAR_IN_NAME 30

int main(void) {
    char team_names[N_OF_TEAMS][MAX_CHAR_IN_NAME];
    double scores[N_OF_TEAMS];
    int n;

    n = read_name_and_score("data.csv",N_OF_TEAMS,team_names,scores);
    if ( n != N_OF_TEAMS) {
        printf("Error, not enough data was read.\n");
        /* It's up to you to decide what to do now */
    }

    /* do whatever you want with data */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also show an example of checking the return of `fscanf` to insure you really have 2 valid conversions. You might also suggest `while (fscanf(filein_ptr, "%[^,],%d\n", team_names[i], &scores[i]) == 2) {}` as a method to read and validate the values. There is nothing wrong with the `for` implementation if you know `N_OF_TEAMS` before hand, but you should still check the `fscanf` return.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Something like this?