# Segmentation Fault when opening a file in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, io, segmentation-fault

I have to write a function that takes in a char pointer as an argument (string for the filename), and reads in the file one word at a time. This is my code so far:

```
void processText(char * filename)

char tmpWord[30];
char tmpFile[200];
char * word;

FILE *fp;

index = 0;

strcpy(tmpFile, filename);

printf("%s\n\n", tmpFile);


fp = fopen(filename, "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Sorry, file does not exist.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (fscanf(fp, "%s", tmpWord) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n", tmpWord);
}
fclose(fp);
```

When I run the program passing in the string "test.txt" it outputs:

```
test.txt


Sorry, file does not exist.
```

Without the if NULL, it simply segfaults after printing test.txt.

If it helps, when I input "test.txt" into fopen instead it runs perfectly, so I know the file path is correct.

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", strlen(filename));` and let me know what you get.

Comment: You may want to look at [**Read from CSV File and Separate Into Strings**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761409/read-from-csv-file-and-separate-into-variable)

Comment: The print statement gives me 9, i also added code to remove the newline at the end of the string (which worked), but it still can't find the file.

Comment: Well if putting `"test.txt"` into fopen works, and putting `filename` into fopen doesn't work, then `filename` is not equal to `"test.txt"`. That's about all I can say based on the information given. You can try printing the contents of `filename` in hex with `for(i=0;i<9;i++)printf("%02x ",filename[i]);`. The output should be `74 65 73 74 2e 74 78 74 00`.

Comment: Good chance to meet Mr debugger

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try and print out your `filename` surrounded in quotes or some other delimiting character, a `#` perhaps? This will show you whether there are any trailing whitespace characters in your filename variable. If there are trailing whitespace characters it may not find your file as it'll be looking for `"test.txt "` instead of `"test.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things to consider when passing a *filename* to a funciton for opening and reading. Not only do you need to *validate* the `fopen` call, but before getting to that point, you should validate that `filename` is a pointer to a valid address and not a `NULL` pointer. Additionally, since you have declared `char tmpWord[30];`, you should (1) initialize the array to zero, and (2 - more importantly), limit the word size read by `fscanf` to `29` characters to insure a `tmpWord` will contain a `null-terminated` string.

Putting the pieces together, you might use the following as `processText`:

```
void processText (char *filename)
{
    if (!filename) {    /* validate filename not NULL */
        fprintf (stderr, "processText() error: invalid argument.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char tmpWord[30] = {0}; /* initialize variables */

    FILE *fp = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {      /* validate file is open */
        fprintf (stderr, "processText() error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("\n reading words from : %s\n\n", filename);

    /* read a maximum of 29 chars in each word into tmpWord & print */
    while (fscanf (fp, " %29s", tmpWord) != EOF)
        printf("  %s\n", tmpWord);

    putchar ('\n');

    fclose(fp);
}
```

A simple example calling `processText` from `main()` could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void processText (char *filename);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate one argument given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename.\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    processText (argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

With test Input/Output being:

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_file_into_words dat/captnjack.txt

 reading words from : dat/captnjack.txt

  This
  is
  a
  tale
  Of
  Captain
  Jack
  Sparrow
  A
  Pirate
  So
  Brave
  On
  the
  Seven
  Seas.
```

Let me know if you have any additional questions, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help! The only question I have is what the putchar at the end does (this is a function I've never seen and am just curious)?

Comment: It doesn't do anything meaningful, I just put it there to add another newline at the end of the file so the output looked better `:)` You can nuke it or move it to `main()`.